# Backup errors after TDE certificate expired and new cert was created with AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server-2016, transparent-data-encryption, ola-hallengren

I have 2 databases in AlwaysOn with TDE enabled.
My TDE cert expired and i created a new one but Ola's Backup script is still failing:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] 
@Databases = 'DB1, DB2', 
@Directory = 'D:\SQL-Backup', 
@CopyOnly='Y', 
@CleanupTime = 120, 
@Compress='Y', 
@BackupType = 'FULL', 
@Verify = 'N', 
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@Encrypt = 'Y',
@EncryptionAlgorithm = 'AES_256',
@ServerCertificate = 'DB_DEK', 
@LogToTable = 'Y'
```

With this error (which is an old Cert):

> Msg 33111, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>
> Cannot find server certificate with thumbprint '0xFAF8C09F62ED7D523AE634133331690FC2FD8367'.

Using native sql backup works:

```
BACKUP Database [DB1] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\SQL-Backup\DB1.bak' 
WITH FORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'DB1-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,
ENCRYPTION(ALGORITHM = AES_256, SERVER CERTIFICATE = [DB_DEK]),  STATS = 10
GO
```

For this to work I had to take the DBs from AlwaysOn.

Has anyone else experienced this type of scenario? And, if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Just curious -- you have Ola's script taking a `COPY_ONLY` backup, but not the native backup?

Comment: Hi Erik i just tried with @CopyOnly = 'N' and get same result;

Comment: is the cert created with same name like u have in Ola's script `DB_DEK` with same algorithm ?

Comment: Kin yes it's exactly the same i triple checked and recreated few times.

Comment: Very interesting thing happens when I recreate the master key and all the Certs and encrypt the db. ola’s script is somehow looking for the previous cert. I tried it few times and same result even after taking full and tlog backups

Answer (score 2):

So after upgrading to SP1 CU7 the backups started working again with TDE.

Comment: Silly question, perhaps, but had you restarted your server between the start of the problem and the update? I just had a cert issue, and I know that if you change the cert, the change doesn't take effect until SQL is restarted....

Comment: yes i did restart. Also not sure if this fix. [link]https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4058175/tde-enabled-database-backup-fails-due-to-inaccessibility-of-ekm-module fixed it